# What will be the regular expression for a string not starting with a substring

Tags: c#, regex

What will be the regular expression to match a word if its not in the start of the string? For example, for `United` to be matched, the string should be `"We are United on it"`. It should not be matched for `"United States"`. I used expression `\w+\s+(United)` but it returns `are United` when matching. I just want `United` to be matched.

What expression I'll be using? And, as I'll replace the matched expression, do I need a loop for replacing multiple occurrences?

Following is some part of the code:

```
     var s = "We are United on it.";
     var regex = new Regex(@"\w+\s+(United)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
         if (regex.IsMatch(s))
         {
             returnString = Regex.Replace(s,@"\w+\s+(United)" , "xyz");
         }
```

Any code example will be greatly helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, when you want to impose a condition on what is *next to* a match, but not include that text *in* the match, you need an *assertion*, for example one of

```
(positive or negative) (look-behind or look-ahead)
```

In this case we want to assert something about what comes just *before* the match, so we need a **look-behind** assertion. And since what we want to assert is: "just before the match, **don't** have the start of the string", we need a **negative look-behind assertion**:

```
string shouldPass = "We are United";
string shouldFail = "United we stand";

var regex = new Regex("(?<!^)United");

Console.WriteLine("{0} result: {1}", shouldPass, regex.IsMatch(shouldPass));
Console.WriteLine("{0} result: {1}", shouldFail, regex.IsMatch(shouldFail));

Console.ReadKey();
```

The syntax for a look-behind negative assertion is `(?<!text)`, replacing `text` with whatever you are saying should *not* appear just before the match.

As an additional point, you don't really need to separately call `.IsMatch` and `.Replace` - `.Replace` will simply do nothing if there is no match.

And you don't need a loop - `.Replace` will replace *all* matches, unless you take specifically call the overload that limits the number of replacements.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=\w+\s+)United
```

matches `United` only if an alphanumeric "word" and whitespace can be found before it.

Therefore,

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("We are united on it.", @"(?<=\w+\s+)United", "xyz", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

will result in

```
We are xyz on it.
```

Another version with different logic (not sure which one you need):

```
United(?!\s+States)
```

matches `United` only if it's not followed by `States`.

These constructions are called [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"^\s*\w+\s+(United)");
```

It means from the start of the string there should be at least some space and some character before you match your word.

Comment: Why have you put the \w in square brackets out of interest? Looks like it should be the same with or without them...

Comment: @Chris was leftover from an original attempt.

Comment: Ah, I thought I had seen it a few times recently (or similar) and wondered if there was some convention at work for trying to make it more readable or something. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that `\w+\s+` are also matched and there for also replaced. I think the simplest would be to put this part into a capturing group and put it also in the replacement.

```
var s = "We are United on it.";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, @"(\w+\s+)United", "$1xyz", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Would print

> We are xyz on it.